# Load balancing kubernetes cluster on budget KVM provider?

Tags: containers, kubernetes, docker-swarm, load-balance

There are a lot of cheap KVM providers these days that offer simple nodes with just a single external IP per node, without any load balancing.

What is a typical budget load balancing solution for this scenario?

I am planning to use either docker swarm or kubernetes as a container orchestration solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how much time you can invest into configuration and your configuration.

I have built my own cluster on AWS using [Nomad](https://www.nomadproject.io) and [Consul](https://www.consul.io) where [Fabio](https://github.com/fabiolb/fabio) was used as Application Load Balancing layer (AWS ALB was lacking for my purposes).

Alternatively if you use k8s and do not need additional ALB you can use DNS RR (multiple A or AAAA records for your domain) or create HAProxy cluster in front of your application.

Comment: Thanks for the help, got it working with RR DNS and this chart: https://kubeapps.com/charts/stable/nginx-ingress , just needed to edit the controller service and add external IPs of the hosts

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using a Cloudflare Argo Tunnel Ingress. It is getting there, but not yet ready for production (17.05.2018).

Saves a lot of time, but is not cheap as it currently requires both Argo & Load Balancing to be turned on.

Both of which use traffic based billing and have no ability to cap costs, or gracefully fall back to pass straight through to origin once a budget has been reached.